# Is there any difference in optimization/speed when using member over function variable?

Tags: c++, optimization

Assume a class that is used to read data from some location and provide it in a different format (not threadsafe). For each item that it reads, it does something like this:

```
TargetDataStruct HostToTargetConverter::Next()
{
  HostDataStruct source;
  sourceData->GetItem(m_index++, &source);

  TargetDataStruct target;
  target.seize = source.day;
  target.have = source.fun;
  return target;
}
```

Would it make any difference to declare `HostDataStruct source` and `TargetDataStruct target` as member variables in terms of speed or optimizability for the compiler? My thought was that the two structures would not need to be pushed on the stack each call and would not need to be initialized every time.

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly I'm not really into assembler to be honest. But I'll give it a try

Comment: The only answer is "it depends". Try both and measure.

Comment: I didn't really understand the differences between the assembler output, but measuring made a huge difference. Stack variables: http://pastebin.com/LyNiagQK Member variables: http://pastebin.com/q9MyuB5N The stack variables version performed almost twice as well without optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is not possible to give a better answer than "it depends".

The differences that result from making the `HostDataStruct` and `TargetDataStruct` into members include;

- Every access of them dereferences a pointer.  Within a member
  function of the containing class accessing `source` and `target`
  evaluates `this->source` and `this->target` respectively (i.e.
  dereferences `this`).
- If the containing object is only constructed once (e.g. not created
  and destroyed repeatedly) then the same goes for its members.  That
  means the overhead of construction is only incurred once (for every instance of the containing object), in comparison with constructing them every time your function is called.
- In your code, the object will be reassigned (i.e. its value changed) within your function.  This is an overhead every time your function is called (and the cost that offsets the fact the object constructor is only invoked once).

The thing is, the costs of these things do vary.   Small objects are inexpensive to construct and destroy whereas larger objects are more expensive to construct and destroy.    A complex constructor (or destructor) makes it better to construct an object only once (even if the object is small, a constructor might access other resources).   Accessing members of a locally constructed object is something that the compiler can implement efficiently, whereas dereferencing a pointer involves more operations, so may not be implemented particularly efficiently by the compiler.

To work out which option gives better run time speed, you'll need to test - for example with a profiler.   The results you get may well be specific to your compiler, host machine configuration, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your code HostDataStruct & TargetDataStruct are in the stack, so the access to read/write are fastest.

To optimize removed all unnecessary operations

Now, the only thing that can make your code faster if you put source and target as members, is if your object constructors take many times ( typically if "new" are called in constructor), and your code called often.

For readability, you can make a convertion constructor like this :

```
TargetDataStruct(const HostDataStruct& value);
```

So your code will be

```
TargetDataStruct HostToTargetConverter::Next()
{
    HostDataStruct source;
    sourceData->GetItem(m_index++, &source);
    return TargetDataStruct(source);
}
```

**But** You can also avoid HostDataStruct allocation if your sourceData container/objects maintains data alive, make your sourceData->GetItem() return a const HostDataStruct&;

```
const HostDataStruct& GetItem(const int p_id);
```

and your code will be something like this :

```
TargetDataStruct HostToTargetConverter::Next()
{
    return TargetDataStruct(sourceData->GetItem(m_index++, &source));
}
```

the last solution should be the fastest, avoiding useless copies, and object construction.

if you still need performance, i.e. : if you code is often called, do the following :
at first call, build your TargetDataStruct in a cache, then always return a reference on your cached data.